# htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php

im trying to get a data from database into a text field:

```
$fothersq=("SELECT others FROM january");
$fothers=mysql_query($fothersq);
<input type="text" placeholder="0" name="febothers" size="11" value="<?php if(@$fothers){echo htmlentities(@$fothers);} ?>">
```

but i got this error in the text field instead.

> **Warning**:  htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be
>   string, resource given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\CashFlow\febprev.php**
>   on line **116**

also in another text field i use this coding just to test:

```
<input type="text" name="febbonus" size="11" placeholder="0" value="<?php if(@$fbonus){echo (@$fbonus);} ?>">
```

and i got this error:

> Resource id #7

any ideas?

Comment: Please [RTFM for `mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query) and its examples.

Comment: Better avoid the `@` sign. It confuses you already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors are telling you exactly what the issue is:

> Warning: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, **resource
>   given** in C:\xampp\htdocs\CashFlow\febprev.php on line 116

And this:

> **Resource** id #7

Both of those errors are telling you that `mysql_query` returns a resource. It is not a string at this point. You *need* to process that resource & act on it. Try this.

```
$fothersq=("SELECT others FROM january");
$fothers=mysql_query($fothersq);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fothers)) {
  echo sprintf('<input type="text" placeholder="0" name="febothers" size="11" value="%s">', (!empty($row['others'] ? htmlentities($row['others']) : '')));
}
```

Also, note that I placed the `<input type="text">` HTML element in an `echo` since the code you have presented makes little sense as straight PHP or HTML or a mix of the two.

**EDIT:** Based on a comment that the original poster might be confused by a ternary operator, here is a modified version of my answer that will achieve the same goal, but in a slightly simpler way:

```
$fothersq=("SELECT others FROM january");
$result=mysql_query($fothersq);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $fothers = '';
  if (!empty($row['others']) {
    $fothers = htmlentities($row['others']);
  }
  echo '<input type="text" placeholder="0" name="febothers" size="11" value="' . $fothers . '">';
}
```

Comment: IMO, the sprintf and the ternary operator make this solution even more complicated for a developer which encountered this basic problem.

Comment: thanks for the input. i got what i wanted through this:  
   $fothersq=("SELECT others FROM january");
   $fothers=mysql_query($fothersq);
   $row=mysql_fetch_array($fothers);
<input type="text" name="febbasic" size="11" placeholder="0" value="<?php if(@$fbresult){echo (@$rowbasic['basic']);} ?>">

Answer (score 1):

Since you ran this

```
$fothers=mysql_query($fothersq);
```

Now `$fothers` will not be a string. It will be a `resource`

But you are passing `$fothers` into the `htmlentities()` which expects a string.

Answer (score 1):

Points to be corrected:

- htmlentities() function converts characters to HTML entities.So it expects a string where in your case your passing resource.
- Your getting `Resource id #7` because you did not fetch anything. After executing, use `mysql_fetch_array` to fetch the row.

Try this:

```
$fothersq=("SELECT others FROM january");
$fothers=mysql_query($fothersq);
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($fothers)) {
?>
<input type="text"  name="febothers" size="11" value="<?php echo (isset($fetch[0])) ?  htmlentities("$fetch[0]") : ''?>">
<?php
}
```